# Carthage Build Failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, carthage

I ran `carthage bootstrap --platform iOS` and got "Skipped installing realm-cocoa.framework binary due to the error: Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 3.1 and the local version is 4.0", and then at the end of the build I got a full on **"Build Failed: Task failed with exit code 65"** error.

It points me to the `derivedDataPath`, and I checked the xcodebuild log for more details where it let me know *"PhaseScriptExecution Download\ Core\ and\ Sync /Users/user/Libary/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.0_9A###/realm-cocoa/v2.10.2/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Script-X#X#X#X#X.sh  (1 failure)".*

But I'm still not totally sure what exactly is happening with Realm Cocoa, or how to fix, do you know?

Comment: You might try running your carthage command again and add the switch --no-use-binaries. (That's two dashes at the front.) This worked for me when dealing with compatibility issues between flavors of Swift 3.x, although I have not tried with 4.0.

Comment: Mike is right. Execute `carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`, you should also check your Swift version on the command line to be equal to the included version on Xcode, just in case you have more than one Xcode version installed. That's `swift --version`, and it should return 4.0. Once you ensure the version run the Carthage command and you'll be done.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I've tried that and it works for the most part when I run into the problem.  I'm not sure if the problem is deeper where I'd need to fix something additional for future problems

Comment: @SRMR Well, you use the `--no-use-binaries` flag because there is a cache for the Realm framework built by a third party (maybe Realm itself?) so the developers would not build the framework and lose time. Anyway, the framework was built with a previous version of Swift and therefore there is an incompatiblity issue. If you build the framework on your own there will be no more issues. Also check the `--cache-builds` flag for Carthage, it will help you to not rebuild every time your dependencies. Cheers!

Comment: @Orlando Awesome info about the --cache-builds flag too! I'm assuming if I use that command once everything is on the right framework version, then everything will work great until there is a new version of Xcode/Swift way in the future where I'll start getting the "incompatible version" warning again, at which point is the best thing to use `carthage build` so it rebuilds the framework?

Comment: That's correct, @SRMR, the `--cache-builds` flag will help you to save on a local cache the checkout source code as well as the built framework. Carthage will compile again if you perform a `carthage update` (a dependency update,) other way the cache will be used as it is. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Orlando awesome that helps so much! If you want to add that as an answer I can mark it and give you the bounty too

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Ensure you're using the latest Swift version, included with Xcode, and then perform `carthage bootstrap --no-use-binaries --platform iOS --cache-builds`

**Long version:**

The error you got from Xcode while building your project, `Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 3.1 and the local version is 4.0`, is due to a download performed by Carthage to get a pre-built version of Realm Framework (this is a time-saver feature but sometimes there are version incompatibilities like this one).

This downloaded pre-built framework was compiled with a previous version of Swift (in this case the error is pointing v3.1 was used.) The solution for this error will be to perform the dependencies installation process using a different command:

`carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`

This will work for the project dependencies build to succeed. Anyway this might take a long time since it will build from scratch the Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework from the core every time the command is executed. So it is possible to enable a local cache for the builds on Carthage. The dependencies can be installed with

`carthage bootstrap --no-use-binaries --platform iOS --cache-builds`

With this options Carthage will:

- bootstrap, so the versions in the `Cartfile.resolved` will be used, no updates.
- `--no-use-binaries` build the dependencies with no downloads of pre-built frameworks (avoiding the version incompatibility.)
- `--platform iOS` will build the dependencies for be used only on iOS, avoiding building frameworks for Apple TV or Mac OS in case the dependency supports it. This will cut a lot of time!
- `--cache-builds` will enable Carthage to store your built dependencies (and use it when re-needed) on a local cache, so even if you perform the command again it will just copy your stored framework, avoiding another time consuming build process.

Comment: Why is it preferable to cache Carthage builds?  We can also use `--no-use-binaries` flag, and it will be the same speed.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the `--no-use-binaries` and the `--cache-builds` are two unrelated flags given to Carthage. The first is used when you don't want to use prebuilt binaries (like the one triggering the build issues on Xcode) and the second is enabling a local cache to speed up the process when you have to (re)install the project dependencies, e.g., maybe on another project using the same dependencies you built from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

Check your application folder and Switch your Xcode version to older version with swift 3.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```