# carthage build failed for realm-cocoa - Task failed with exit code 65:

Tags: xcode, build, realm, carthage

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions provided out there worked for me.

I've cloned nextcloud-ios app, where dependancies are managed with carthage. When I try to build the realm-cocoa dependancy with `carthage build realm-cocoa --platform ios --no-use-binaries --cache-builds` I got build failed message:

```
*** No cache found for realm-cocoa, building with all downstream dependencies
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/60/rmt9jlwd01l3h3srvjnx7r7w0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.u6zLJP.log
*** Building scheme "Realm" in Realm.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "RealmSwift" in Realm.xcworkspace
Build Failed
    Task failed with exit code 65:
    /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/manishkungwani/repos/brilcloud-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/realm-cocoa/Carthage/Realm.xcworkspace -scheme RealmSwift -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/manishkungwani/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.3_10G8/realm-cocoa/v3.13.1 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/60/rmt9jlwd01l3h3srvjnx7r7w0000gn/T/realm-cocoa SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/manishkungwani/repos/brilcloud-ios/Carthage/Checkouts/realm-cocoa)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/60/rmt9jlwd01l3h3srvjnx7r7w0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.u6zLJP.log
```

I've two version of xcode on my system: 11.4 and 10.3, and tried every possible solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915496/3455666), tried switching command line tools to xcode 10.3, but no luck. Please help.

Comment: Hi, you got any solution for it ?

Comment: @karanatwal.github.io Hi, not yet. The issue was for one of my projects which is no longer under maintenance.